# Running Custom Prediction with Google Cloud AI Platform and GPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am trying to deploy a MaskRCNN model to the GCP AI platform. The default online prediction doesn't work for me because my input size is bigger than the allowed limit. So, I decided to go ahead with the custom prediction route.

With respect to custom prediction, I am trying to use a larger machine-type than what is provided by default because my model is big and needs more memory than what the default one ( mls1-c1-m2 ) provides.

I want to deploy the model with n1-standard-4  machine type, and following is the command I am running:

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $VERSION_NAME   --model $MODEL_NAME   --runtime-version 1.14   --python-version 3.5   --origin $MODEL_DIR   --package-uris gs://pred_02/staging/my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz --framework tensorflow  --prediction-class predictor.MyPredictor --machine-type n1-standard-4
```

but this throws an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Machine type n1-standard-4 only support FRAMEWORK_TENSORFLOW
```

I tried different variations of --framework arg as well but all of them throw some similar error. So, why is it throwing this error?

If this works, then my idea is to use this machine type with a k80 accelerator. And this would be my second question? can I run it with an accelerator for custom prediction?

Comment: Is your model is a Tensorflow model compliant with version 1.14 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--prediction-class` does not work on n1 machine types yet. You could use `mls1-c4-m2` machines till then. Check for machine types [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/machine-types-online-prediction#differences) to learn about the constraints for each machine type.

Custom prediction routines are still evolving(beta). You should check for updates [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/custom-prediction-routines).

Comment: So, turns our my model uses more memory than what is provided with mls1-c4-m2, so , I had to use an alpha version machine type "mls1-c4-m4" . I am able to get the results with that but it's extremely slow.

Comment: Still only able to load upto 500MB model.